# Date format Query in cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am executing this query :

```
select createdate from OITM_CLONE where ItemCode ='bk1109' and U_SLV ='f'
```

it gives output like  '2013-05-04 02:28:34.000'

but i want to get date in variable so am using this query

```
declare @da as varchar (20)
declare @d as varchar(max)
set @d=(select createdate from OITM_CLONE where ItemCode ='bk1109' and U_SLV ='f')
select @d
```

but it gives output like  'May  4 2013  2:28AM'

i need this output format '2013-05-04 02:28:34.000'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a specific format (it's usually best to leave datetime data *as* datetime data and do the formatting elsewhere), you need to use [`CONVERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and tell it exactly how you want the formatting performed:

```
set @d=(select CONVERT(varchar(max),createdate,121) from OITM_CLONE where ItemCode ='bk1109' and U_SLV ='f')
```

Where `121` is the "ODBC Canonical (with milliseconds)" format.

Answer (score 0):

As shown below, you can simply declare @d as datetime to avoid the CONVERT

```
if exists
(
    select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
    where id = object_id(N'[tempdb].dbo.[#ThisTable]')
)
DROP TABLE #ThisTable
;
create table #ThisTable
(
    ItemCode tinyint
    ,createdate datetime
)
;
INSERT INTO #ThisTable
(ItemCode,createdate)
VALUES
(1,'2013-05-04 02:28:34.000')
,(2,'2013-05-04 02:28:34.000')
;
declare @da as varchar (20) ;
declare @d as varchar(max) ;
declare @dt as datetime ;
set @d=(select createdate from #ThisTable where ItemCode = 1)
set @dt=(select createdate from #ThisTable where ItemCode = 2)
select * from #ThisTable ;
select @d ;
select @dt ;
```

select @d ;
May  4 2013  2:28AM

select @dt ;
2013-05-04 02:28:34.000